# Call iFrame button and then parent button

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-callback

I am having a button inside iFrame and a button in a parent window. Button inside iFrame is triggered from parent window. I have certain set of code that is to be executed from both buttons. A part of code is specific to iFrame and a part of code is specific to Parent window. I am able to trigger the iFrame button but the problem is parent window code runs before iFrame button has completed it's operation.

Please help me to achieve this.

Please suggest and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can the solution involve code changes to both documents? i.e. Do you have control over the content in the iFrame, or does this have to work with your code in the parent and someone else's page in the iFrame?

Comment: Yes I am having control over both parent and iFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the outer document, set up button2 to create a new event containing the chain of actions you want to execute after button1 completes, and dispatch it to the inner button.

Depending on what actions you want performed, you may have to declare any variables within this click handler that the deferred actions will need so that they are part of the closure.

```
$(function(){
    $("#button2").click(function(e){
        var action = function() {
            setTimeout(function(){alert("button2 action")},6000);
        }
        var innerButton = $("iframe#frame").contents()
            .find("#button1");
        e.detail = action;
        var evt = new CustomEvent('click',e);
        innerButton[0].dispatchEvent(evt);
    });
});
```

In the inner document, after performing the normal action for the button click, check to see if additional actions were passed with the event, and execute them.

```
$(function () {
    $("#button1").click(function (evt) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert("button1 click");
            if (typeof evt.originalEvent.detail == 'function') evt.originalEvent.detail(evt);
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

Here are a pair of jsFiddles, one for the [inner](http://jsfiddle.net/nhzzj5bt/), and another one for the [outer](http://jsfiddle.net/sj83jo7j/1/) that includes the inner in a (not very legibile) iframe.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I will look into the details for the above code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way,

```
$("#btnButton2").hide();
$("#btnButton2").click(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Hello from Button 2");
    }, 3000);
});

$("#btnButton1").click(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Hello from Button 1");
        $("#btnButton2").show().click();
    }, 6000);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7nrkfj00/10/)

Comment: Sorry Anoop this does not solve my problem. I have an iFrame and I am calling a button inside iFrame from parent window. What I want is that after the click event of iFrame is finished then only I want the code for the window button to be executed. Please advise.